# Sending a file from android application to raspberry pi using SSH

Tags: java, android, ssh, raspberry-pi, file-transfer

I am trying to send a file from an android app to a RaspberryPi over WIFI.

I can connect to the RPI and send it commands via SSH.

this is the function that i am using to send the ssh command:

```java
public static String executeRemoteCommand(final String username, final String password, final String hostname, final int port, final File file)
            throws Exception {

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
        session.setPassword(password);

        // Avoid asking for key confirmation
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(prop);

        session.connect();

        // SSH Channel
        ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec)
                session.openChannel("exec");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        channelssh.setOutputStream(baos);

        // Execute command

        channelssh.setCommand("scp " + file + " " + username + "@" + hostname + ":/home/pi/Desktop");
        channelssh.connect();
        try{Thread.sleep(5000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        channelssh.disconnect();
        return baos.toString();
    }
```

and this is the SSH command that is going to be sent

```
scp /storage/emulated/0/Download/201906071017.txt pi@192.168.4.1:/home/pi/Desktop
```

I tried running the SSH command on windows terminal and it uploads the file successfully

Edit:

I added this code between the `.connect()` and `.disconnect()` to wait until i get a response from the command to disconnect from the RPi

```java
        channelssh.setErrStream(System.err);

        InputStream in=channelssh.getInputStream();

        channelssh.connect();

        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        while(true){
            while(in.available()>0){
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if(channelssh.isClosed()){
                if(in.available()>0) continue;
                System.out.println("exit-status: "+channelssh.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        }

        channelssh.disconnect();
```

Now i am getting permission denied in the logs, the username and password are correct.

```
W/System.err: Permission denied, please try again.
W/System.err: Permission denied, please try again.
W/System.err: Permission denied (publickey,password).
W/System.err: lost connection
I/System.out: exit-status: 1
```

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: i dont get any error messages but the file does not appear on the RPI

Comment: I'll delete my answer, it doesn't solve your problem. You definitely need to do something between the connect and disconnect. You probably need to write the file to the outputstream, but you might need to change the scp command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it!!
I ended up using the sftp service to upload the file
i was using `ChannelSsh` with `ChannelExec`. I should have used `ChannelSftp`

Here is the working code

```java
package com.example.a.sitetool;

import android.util.Log;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class RpiUpdate {


    public static String executeRemoteCommand(final String username, final String password, final String hostname, final int port, final File file)
            throws Exception {

        Log.d("MainActivity", "Entered executeRemoteCommand");

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
        session.setPassword(password);

        // Avoid asking for key confirmation
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(prop);

        session.connect();

        // SSH Channel
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        ChannelSftp channelsftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        channelsftp.cd("/home/pi/Desktop");
        channelsftp.put(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName());
        channelsftp.setOutputStream(baos);

        // Execute command
        channelsftp.put(file.getName(),"/home/pi/Desktop");

        InputStream in=channelsftp.getInputStream();

        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        while(true){
            while(in.available()>0){
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if(channelsftp.isClosed()){
                if(in.available()>0) continue;
                System.out.println("exit-status: "+channelsftp.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
        }

        channel.disconnect();

        return baos.toString();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I optimized the code and removed the `ByteArrayOutputStream` as it is not needed for `Channelsftp`. This change led to the return being `void` instead of `String`
I also added the ability to change the permission of the outputted file.

```java
package com.example.a.sitetool;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Properties;

public class RpiUpdate {
    private static boolean success;


    public static void update() {
        //TODO add online version checking and download
        if (success)
            uploadFile();

    }

    private static void uploadFile() {
        Log.d("RPIUpdate", "Entered upload File");
        success=false;
        new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                try {
                    executeRemoteCommand("pi", "rbs", "192.168.4.1", 22);
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "File Uploaded");
                    success = true;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Failed to upload file");
                    success = false;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute(1);
    }


public static void executeRemoteCommand(final String username, final String password, final String hostname, final int port)
            throws Exception {
        Log.d("RPiUpdate", "Entered executeRemoteCommand");

        //Creating the path on android to bbserver.py
        File root;
        root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Download");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(root, "bbserver.py");

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, port);
        session.setPassword(password);

        // Avoid asking for key confirmation
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(prop);

        session.connect();

        //SFTP setup
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();

        ChannelSftp channelsftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        //Renaming the old bbserver.py
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd:HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date now = new Date();
        channelsftp.cd("/home/pi/Desktop");
        // 384 in octal is 600. This makes the file non executable. only readable and writable

        channelsftp.chmod(384, "/home/pi/Desktop/bbserver.py");

        channelsftp.rename("/home/pi/Desktop/bbserver.py", "/home/pi/Desktop/bbserver" + formatter.format(now) + ".py");

        //sending the new bbserver.py file
        channelsftp.put(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName());
        Log.d("RPiUpdate", "Sent file");

        //511 in octal is 777. This gives the file all available permissions(read, write, execute). thus making the file an executable

        channelsftp.chmod(511, "/home/pi/Desktop/" + file.getName());
        Log.d("RPiUpdate", "Changed permissions");

        channel.disconnect();

    }
```

Comment: Hey J.Raad! I am looking into doing something similar but backwards: sending files (images) from the PI to an android app. Do you have anything idea/directtion?